# adding a div with bootstrap button to jquery datatable column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have following DataTable

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#productTable").DataTable({
                    "info": false,
                    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                    "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                    "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Home/LoadProductData",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                            { "data": "Product_ID", "name": "Product_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                            { "data": "Product_Title", "name": "Product_Title", "autoWidth": true }                               
                               ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Now I want to add following `div` which has bootstrap button

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="CreateButton">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Product_Edit","Home", new { })';return false;">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Is this possible to insert directly? If not, how to configure this?

Comment: you want to add this button in a column for all rows?

Answer (score 0):

use [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render):

```
'columns': [
            {
                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>';
                }
            },
...
```

I notice that you're using MVC Razor syntax to generate the Url, which makes me think that you're including the datatables initialisation code in the View.  To get round this you need to generate the button like this:

```
<a class=\'btn\' href=\'' + $("#rooturl").val() + '/Home/Product_Edit/' + full[0] + '\'>Edit</a>';
```

`$("#rooturl")` is a hidden field containing the application url.
I've assumed the the `Product_Edit` action method accepts a parameter of `Product_ID`.  This way you're using the datatable row data to append the id to the url.